# moving from tableview to another uiviewcontroller of the storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

when pressing a row of the table view I want to move in another screen of my storyboard.

1) I do not want to use navigation controller, or do i have to?

So I tried this code:

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *vc=[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CenterMain"];
    [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentedViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

inside my `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

I am getting this warning:

```
Instance method '-presentedViewController:animated:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

and this error when running:

```
MainMap presentedViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72a2070
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainMap presentedViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72a2070'
```

2) If using navigationController with this code:

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CenterMain"] animated:YES];
```

it works but the thing is that I do not want to see the bar of the navigation controller on the top.

So I want either to helo with the 1, or tell how to erase the top bar in sollution 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UIViewController` `- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated` or `- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden;` method.  So in your case,

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

if you just want it hidden, or:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

if you want to animate while hiding.

Comment: thanks! thas was easier than trying to remove my navigation controller.